# Set background for FMX popup window

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, popupwindow

I have an FMX Android project compiled with Delphi 10.1 Berlin.  The user needs to select from 19 values to run it and I use a TPopupBox component to display 19 TRadioButtons that show in 3 columns of 7+7+5 buttons for that selection.

The default is for a transparent popup window which is useless, so I edited the style to add a white TRectangle to the background of the popup window which works, but only if I size the rectangle to match the size of the popup.  Aligning the rectangle to client or contents only sets an opaque background to the first row of radio buttons. I have 2 questions:

1. How can I auto size the rectangle rather than fixing it at design time to match what I calculate will be set for popup.bounds?
2. Is adding a TRectangle to the style background the best way to get an opaque control?

I have tried all obvious align options and searched the internet.  Somebody suggested deleting 'background' from the style list but that did not work. Somebody else suggested editing the manifest but my manifest just gets overwritten when I compile.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem in the IDE and in a Windows project or do you only see it on a phone? Why did you choose a `TPopupBox`? Help says about `TPopupBox`: *Represents a single-line text box that, when clicked, displays a pop-up menu.* Ergo, it is not really designed to house a number of subcomponents.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wrote erroneously `TPopupBox` and probably meant to write `TPopup`. That is anyway what you should use for popup windows.

You may want to create a new project, for testing purposes. Add a button near top left. This will show and hide the popup window.

Add a `TPopup` and size it as you wish, and set `Visible := True`.

Add a rectangle inside the popup and set its `Align` property to `Contents`. Set its `Fill.Color` property as you wish. Add `TRadiobuttons` as you wish, on the rectangle.

Finally, the code to toggle the popup visibility (but **see notes in Help**):

```
Popup1.IsOpen := not Popup1.IsOpen;
```

Please note! There are many properties that jointly affect the placement of the `TPopup`: `Placement`, `PlacementRectangle`, `PlacementTarget`. As I don't know your needs, I leave it to you to decide what to use.

A sample test case:

[image]

Here `PlacementTarget` is `Button1` and `Placement` is `Bottom`.

Comment: I used TPopupBox so I will change it when I have time tomorrow.  Thanks for reply.